# Overlaying image and using JS to move one

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have 2 overlayed images then use JavaScript to move the top one. I can either not overlay them and JS moves them fine, or overlay them and the JS does not move them

```js
document.getElementById('previewImg').style.top = "100px";
```

```css
.parentPreview {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .preview1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .preview2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 11px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parentPreview">
      <img class="preview1" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=text" />
       <img id="previewImg" class="preview2" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=text2" />
    </div>
```

Comment: wrap `js` code inside `<script>` tag

Comment: Apologies, it is, struggle to use the editor here to write my question!

Comment: `getElementById` is a function and must be used with `()` instead of arrays `[]`. `document.getElementById('previewImg').style.top = "100px";`

Comment: 11 out of 10.  Well done.  All sorted.  Thank you!